# semantic-ui fixed menu for mobile navigation

Tags: reactjs, navigation, semantic-ui

I am having a semantic ui menu fixed to the bottom, but I don't understand how to to navigate to different pages using it without refreshing the whole page (including the menu). I am working with reactjs and the documentation does not provide any example on how to use navigation with a menu.

```
class FooterMenu extends Component {
  state = {}

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: name });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state
  return (
  <div>
    <Menu fixed={'bottom'} widths={4} secondary pointing>
      <Menu.Item
         name='dashboard'
        onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        active={this.props.dashActive}
      >
        <img src={dasha} className="icon-style" />
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item
        name='activities'
        // active={activeItem === 'activities'}
        onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        active={this.props.activitiesActive}
      >
        <img src={clocko} className="icon-style"/>
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item
        name='newActivity'
        active={activeItem === 'newActivity'}
        onClick={this.handleItemClick}
      >
        <img src={bello} className="icon-style"/>
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item
        href='#'
        name='profile'
        active={activeItem === 'profile'}
        onClick={this.handleItemClick}
      >
        <img src={usero} className="icon-style"/>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>

    {/* <div className="ui active tab">
      <Dashboard />
    </div> */}

  </div>
      );
    }
}

export default FooterMenu;
```

Answer (score -1):

try to call it inside App.js and use react-router